# Desktop Ubuntu 20 04 nginx не видет server_name и возвращает ошибку IP address could not be found. что делать?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, vmware

На VMware запустил Ubuntu 20.04
установил nginx, php, mysql

nginx работает без проблем, `sudo nginx -t`  выполняется без ошибок,
localhost также работает и возвращает nginx default страницу,

Но проблема в том что service_name домейни не работают и возвращают ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите пожалуйста, уже отчаялся и думаю может проблема в VMware е ?

Вот конфигурационный файл

```
 server {
  listen 80;

  root /var/www/loft.loc/public/;
  index index.php;

  server_name loft.loc;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
     try_files $uri =404;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     include fastcgi_params;
  }
 }
```

Comment: `loft.loc` резольвится в нужный IP? В DNS или hosts прописали?

Comment: @vp_arth Не понял вопрос, 
`loft.loc`  мой  локальный домен  , к DNS не имеет ни какого значения,  папка host как понимаю есть в системе window у меня установлена ubuntu.

Comment: @vp_arth   Цель   развернуть локально проект,  для этого использую VMware  где установил  ubuntu 20.04    веб сервер nginx,  все работает кроме server_name ов 
то есть  любое server_name  имя  nginx возвращает туже ошибку.

Comment: @vp_arth   localhost  работает правильно nginx возвращает все как надо, вот думаю  перевести весь код на localhost, `var/www/html`  но  тут не останется места для другого проекта

Comment: А ты бридж между виндой и вмваром сделай или нат с порта ПК на порт внутри вм. если в виртуализации ты новичок, то можешь поставить WSL, там графики не будет, но зато у тебя не будет проблем с доступом к IP-адресам своего же пк и с доступом к дискам винды.

Comment: Да  WSL не использовал  попробую